# datatables sort by column name

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable

Shortly I need having column name instead of column number when apply sorting or searches.
I know it's not implemented and the developer has said more times that he will be support it in the next version but I'm thinking about now.
I'm using server side pagination so I'm using ajax.data.
I would simply add new value to d.order[0] object sent by datatable.
This is my pseudo:

```
vat table = $('#foo').DataTable({
"processing": true, 
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
 "url": uri_api,
 "method": "POST",
 "data": function(d) {
   if len(table.columns(0).data.tfoot.placeholder)>0 than d.order[0]['col_name']='col0name'
   if len(table.columns(1).data.tfoot.placeholder)>0 than d.order[1]['col_name']='col1name'
   return json.stringify(d);
 }
"columns": [
  { "data": "bar" },
  { "data": "baz" }
 ]
});
```

This is pure pseudocode, I don't know how to code it. Also with pure js. If in ajax part I use $(this) it uses the whole jquery library.
Any hints?

Comment: When you use `"serverSide": true`, you apply sorting, filtering, and paging logic on the server, not in the browser - and then the server returns the relevant sorted/filtered/paged data as its response. The server uses the request data automatically sent from DataTables to do this. See the "Sent Parameters" section of the [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) documentation.

Comment: When serverside is true the backend don't handle it but just answer. To do it server needs share a table structure because datatable send cardinal integers to filter or sort it's data. That is a big limit because I can't hide or move columns because it will corrupt the table structure shared with server previously.

Comment: Because if I have three columns in db they are 0 foo, 1 bar, 2 baz.
Datatable instead know 1 foo 2 bar 3 baz, so if I move foo after bar the new table structure will be 0 bar 1 foo 2 baz and this is ONLY in the frontend. The backend doesn't know about this change, the backend will keep know 0 foo 1 bar 2 baz

Comment: If you [give names to your columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax), then the request will contain the data you need. See the `columns[i][name]` parameter in the link I shared in my first comment. Using that, you will know which column (by name) is in which position (by index).

Comment: Sorry - that was the wrong link in my last comment. This is the correct one: [columns.name](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name).

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to andrewjames I FIXED my issue, and works very fast too!
Based on his tips I searched "datatables columns name with ajax data" and I found this link:
[Using column names with DataTables with AJAX data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124812/using-column-names-with-datatables-with-ajax-data-source)
Basically I don't followed the solution with green flag, that solution didin't work for me.
I used ahmeti answer, I have added this lines:

```
fnServerParams: function(data) {
    data['order'].forEach(function(items, index) {
        data['order'][index]['column_name'] = data['columns'][items.column]['data'];
  });
},
```

Regards.